# system of linear equations - Markov chain

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I am trying to model a system using a continuous-time Markov chain. I want to calculate the probability that a user **entering the system at a state** $s$ will encounter an event $E$ (while staying in the system).

The transition probability matrix $T$ is already computed.

For some states $s$ in the state space the probability $p(E,s) = 1$.

For the rest of the states $p(E,s) = \sum \nolimits_{s'} p(E,s') T(s,s') $

Any idea of how can I solve it?

Comment: So, to simplify, you want to calculate the probability that the system ever reaches a certain set of states from a given initial state?

Comment: I want to calculate the probability of a user seeing E happening during his sojourn in the system given the initial state (when he accessed the system)

Comment: Yes, but the probability of "seeing $E$" is $1$ if you're in a certain set of states, and otherwise it's the probability of "seeing $E$" in the state you reach through a transition -- so isn't that just an unnecessarily roundabout way of expressing the probability of at some point reaching that certain set of states?

Comment: let's denote the set of states with $p(E,s) = 1$ by$ X$, and the whole state space by $S$. if the user enters the system at a state $s$ in $X$, then for sure, he will see $E$. But if he enters the system at a state s in $S \setminus X$ then I do not know the probability of "seeing $E$, I have to calculate it for the other states.

Comment: I am sorry. You are right, in the end, it is the probability of the system visiting a state $s \in X$ during the sojourn of the user, given that he entered the system at a state $s \in S \setminus X$